# FlatMap an iterable and combine it back into iterable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an API that returns a `Single`. This `Single` contains a list of values, let's say `String` values. When I am calling this object, I get that `Single` and have to filter some values from it and return back another `Single`. I'm trying to achieve something like in this simplified test:

```
@Test
public void filterTest() {

    List<String> sourceList = Arrays.asList("email", "phone", "smoke", "email", "phone", "fax", "email");

    Single.just(sourceList)
            .toObservable()
            .flatMap(source -> {
                return Observable.from(source);
            })
            .filter(source -> !source.equals("email"))
            .groupBy(/* criteria? */)
            //how to extract single list from groupBy or 
            //is there another opposite function for flatMap?
            .toSingle()
            .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `filter(source -> Observable.from(source).equals("email"))` ?

Comment: Also, your `Observable` class looks to be ignoring [the symmetric requirement of `equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) (because `"email".equals(source)` will always return false). This will inevitably lead to problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```java
Single.just(sourceList)
        .flattenAsObservable(source -> source)
        .filter(source -> !source.equals("email"))
        .toList()
        .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

or

```java
 Observable.fromIterable(sourceList)
        .filter(source -> !source.equals("email"))
        .toList()
        .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

Comment: I've found a similar solution but I like `flattenAsObservable` call. I'll try it ASAP.